# Trying to mount a TV to the wall and cannot find a stud to save my life

Tags: walls, mounting, television

I am trying to mount my TV with a vertical mount to the wall. I cannot find any vertical studs however, only what feels like horizontal ones, which is strange to me. The power outlets are mounted ON the wall, rather than in the wall.

I have tried a stud finder, knocking, drilling holes every two inches, all nothing. I used a magnet and found a metal spot. Drilling under it found nothing but there was resistance to the side. What is going on? How do I mount a TV to this wall?

I am attempting to get pictures but my phone keeps taking them in too large a size

Comment: Outlets "on" the wall often means that behind the drywall is concrete blocks or similar - i.e., something other than a hollow wall.

Comment: go outside..is the home made of bricks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find studs when stud finders won't work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-find-studs-when-stud-finders-wont-work?rq=1)

Comment: Upload your photos to https://imgur.com and post the links, or resize them.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact is drywall stuck directly on CMU, though?

Comment: @Huesmann No. But could use strips of wood (2x4 = 1.5x3.5, or possibly smaller) attached to the concrete blocks and then drywall on those strips. If so, those strips could be horizontal rather than vertical.

Answer (score 0):

First, know that studs are 1-1/2" thick, so drilling holes spaced 2" can still miss the studs.

To find the studs once you make a hole, use a soft metal wire, eg a coat hanger with a 90° bend about 10". Insert it into the hole past the bend, then rotate it until you hit a stud.

It could always be the case that you are hanging the TV into a wall with an irregular pattern of studs, eg, a window that was covered, etc. But if you drill enough small holes, you'll eventually find studs.